Algorithm to Solve Constrained Fermat Weber
Let $C_{i} 1 \leq i \leq N$ be closed, convex subsets of Hilbert space $H$. Give an algorithm to solve the following constrained Fermat-Weber-Heron problem.
$$ \min_{x \in C_{1}} \sum_{i=2}^N d_{C_i} $$
My attempt:
Write the objective function as
$$ \min_{x \in H} i_{C_{1}} + \sum_{i=2}^N d_{C_i}$$
Can I apply Douglas Rashford algorithm? But, that is for the sum of two functions. So how can I proceed?

Hint: To use Douglas-Rachford, try out the "product space technique", e.g., outlined in Section 5.1 (specifically Example 5.11) of these notes.
